# How to throw a validation error with Pydantic StrictFloat on float("nan")?

Tags: python, pydantic

I am using Pydantic's [strict types](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/types/#strict-types) and want to throw an error when a `StrictFloat` field is assigned a `float("nan")` value.

Here's an example:

```py
from typing import List, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel, StrictFloat, StrictInt


class StrictNumbers(BaseModel):
    values: List[Union[StrictFloat, StrictInt]]


# throws no validation error
my_model = StrictNumbers(values=[1, 2.0, float("nan")])

# throws a validation error
# my_model = StrictNumbers(values=[1, 2.0, None])

print(my_model)
```

What's the easiest way to throw an error on `float("nan")` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple field validator with [`each_item=True`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/#subclass-validators-and-each_item) should do the trick:

```py
from math import isnan

from pydantic import BaseModel, StrictFloat, StrictInt, validator


class StrictNumbers(BaseModel):
    values: list[StrictFloat | StrictInt]

    @validator("values", each_item=True)
    def disallow_nan(cls, v: float) -> float:
        if isnan(v):
            raise ValueError("NaN values are not allowed")
        return v
```

Demo:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from pydantic import ValidationError

    try:
        StrictNumbers(values=[1, 2.0, float("nan")])
    except ValidationError as err:
        print(err.json(indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
[
    {
        "loc": [
            "values",
            2
        ],
        "msg": "NaN values are not allowed",
        "type": "value_error"
    }
]
```

Side note: The reason I annotated `v: float` inside the validation method is because from a typing perspective `int` is a subtype of `float` (even though in the strict sense of Pydantic field types it is not). Also, I am using the more current syntax for type unions with the `|` symbol available from `3.10` onward and the built-in [generic alias type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#generic-alias-type) of `list` instead of `typing.List`, which is the recommended way since `3.9`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import math
from pydantic import (
    BaseModel,
    StrictInt,
    StrictFloat,
    validator,
    ValidationError
)

from typing import List, Union


class StrictNumbers(BaseModel):
    values: List[Union[StrictFloat, StrictInt]]

    @validator('values')
    def check_nan(cls, values):
        for v in values:
            if math.isnan(v):
                raise ValueError("Nan Not Allowed")
        return values


# throws a validation error
my_model = StrictNumbers(values=[1, 2.0, float("nan")])

print(my_model)
```